# Generic function accept type parameter of <T<U>>?

Tags: c#

I'm refactoring the following code to use generic to reduce the methods:

```
class CInt  { public int P1 { get; set; } }
class CDate { public DateTime P1 { get; set; } }
class CStr  { public string P1 { get; set; } }

static IEnumerable<CInt>  Fun(IEnumerable<CInt> p) { .... }
static IEnumerable<CDate> Fun(IEnumerable<CDate> p) { .... }
static IEnumerable<CStr>  Fun(IEnumerable<CStr> p) { .... }
```

To:

```
interface IBase<T> { T P1 { get; set; } }
class CInt  : IBase<int> { public int P1 { get; set; } }
class CDate : IBase<DateTime> { public DateTime P1 { get; set; } }
class CStr  : IBase<string> { public string P1 { get; set; } }

static IEnumerable<T> Fun<T, U>(IEnumerable<T> p) where T : IBase<U> { 
    //.... 
    var t = p.First().P1;
    //....
    return null;
}
var cints = new List<CInt> { new CInt() };
var result = Fun1<IBase<int>, int>(cints);
```

Is it possible to remove the type parameter `U` in above function since `T` can decide what `U` is. Or something like

```
static IEnumerable<IBase<S>> Fun<IBase<S>>(IEnumerable<IBase<S>> p) { .... }
```

Or it's not possible unless C# support higher kinded type?

Comment: Looks to me the problem is that there is not much use for this... What is the semantical interpretation of `U` in terms of `T`. Since you don't know anything about `T`, it is pointless.

Comment: What is actually occurring with `U`? If you just need a type, you could try just using reflection and pulling the first generic type of `T`'s `IBase` interface.

Comment: Your last line is close - just change `Fun<IBase<S>>` to `Fun<S>`.

Comment: If you only have three things then just write three methods that take the three things.  Use generics when you want to be able to write a type of **anything**. You want to have a list of functions, a list of apples, a list of rectangles, so list is generic. If you only want to have a Fun of ints, bools and strings, then just stick with your existing code.

Comment: @EricLippert I will have about six cases, maybe more - depends on the basic data types.

Comment: Six is still a small number. Look at the implementation of, say Sum in the LINQ sequence operations library. There are dozens of them, because there are *only dozens* of types for which it makes sense to sum, not *infinitely many*.

Comment: Yes, it's still small. However, the content of the methods are almost the same so it looks ugly copy/paste in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "unless C# support higher order type", but one possible solution is to have `IBase<T>` extend a non-generic `IBase` and use *that* for your constraint on `Fun`:

```
interface IBase { }
interface IBase<T> : IBase { T P1 { get; set; } }

static IEnumerable<T> Fun<T>(IEnumerable<T> p) where T : IBase { .... }
```

Of course, if you *use* the generic type of `IBase<T>` in `Fun` then you *have* to declare is as a second generic parameter.

Comment: This won't work if the function need to access `P1` of T in the body. I've updated the question with some sample accessing code.

Comment: Like my last sentence says, if your internal code depends on the type of `U` (even indirectly by calling other generic functions like you do), then you have to add it as a generic parameter.